# QML Window min-width

Tags: qt, text, qt4, qml

I'm creating a window with QML and the code below. How can I set a min-width for the window so that I can't resize less than the values I define?

```
Rectangle {
    color: red;
    width: 300
    height: 100
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QDeclarativeView view;

    view.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("QML/main.qml"));
    view.setResizeMode(QDeclarativeView::SizeRootObjectToView);
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
view.setMinimumSize(QSize(min-width,min-height));
```

Comment: thank you it works. Just a question: isn't there a method to set it in the QML file? I think it would be more appropriate there because it's a graphics-related thing

Comment: I haven't used qml. But for sure there will be property minimumsize that can be set in qml file.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know, which version of QML you're using, but if you can youse QtQuick 2, then you would set `ApplicationWindow` as your toplevel Item in QML like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: appWnd
    minimumWidth: 300
    minimumHeight: 300
}
```

You can also have a look at `implicitWidth` and `implicitHeight` properties for each particular QML type and set `appWnd` minimumWidth/Height to be implicitWidth/Height of containing layout. For example:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0

ApplicationWindow
{
    minimumWidth: gridLayout.implicitWidth
    minimumHeight: gridLayout.implicitHeight
    height: 500
    width: 500

    color: "gold"

    GridLayout {
        id: gridLayout
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        columns: 2

        Button {text: "Push me" }
        Button {text: "Push me" }
        Button {text: "Push me" }
        Button {text: "Push me" }
        Button {text: "Push me" }
        Button {text: "Push me" }
    }

}
```

This will not let the app window scale smaller than the controls it contains (as implicit layout's width and height is equal to the sum of contained items implicit widths and heights).

You can also bind to the absolute minimum width of the layout by using `gridLayout.Layout.minimumWidth`, as described [in the docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquicklayouts-overview.html#connecting-windows-and-layouts).

Comment: At the time of writing there was no ApplicationWindow component, however now your reply is the correct one

Comment: @Stefano, right, I didn't look at the year of asking, just month :(